# I need to wrap a result set of xml data with a parent tag

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table with a column of type `xml`. I'd like to wrap the result set in a parent tag.

For example:

Here is the table result set:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyColorTable
```

Result :

```
<Color>Red</Color>
<Color>Orange</Color>
<Color>Yellow</Color>
<Color>Green</Color>
<Color>Blue</Color>
<Color>Indigo</Color>
<Color>Violet</Color>
```

I would like a query that will set `@MyXml` as below:

```
DECLARE @MyXml xml
SELECT @MyXml
```

Desired output:

```
<Colors>
        <Color>Red</Color>
        <Color>Orange</Color>
        <Color>Yellow</Color>
        <Color>Green</Color>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
        <Color>Indigo</Color>
        <Color>Violet</Color>
</Colors>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **Updated solution:**

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (Col1 XML);
INSERT @MyTable VALUES (N'<Color>Red</Color>');
INSERT @MyTable VALUES (N'<Color>Orange</Color>');
INSERT @MyTable VALUES (N'<Color>Yellow</Color>');
INSERT @MyTable VALUES (N'<Color>Blue</Color>');
INSERT @MyTable VALUES (N'<Color>Green</Color>');
INSERT @MyTable VALUES (N'<Color>Indigo</Color>');
INSERT @MyTable VALUES (N'<Color>Violet</Color>');

SELECT  t.Col1 AS '*'
FROM    @MyTable t
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Colors');
```

Output:

```
<Colors>
  <Color>Red</Color>
  <Color>Orange</Color>
  <Color>Yellow</Color>
  <Color>Blue</Color>
  <Color>Green</Color>
  <Color>Indigo</Color>
  <Color>Violet</Color>
</Colors>
```

2) If you want to change just the content of `@MyXML` variable then one solution is to use [`query` method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx) thus:

```
DECLARE @MyXml XML;

SET @MyXML = N'
<Color>Red</Color>
<Color>Orange</Color>
<Color>Yellow</Color>
<Color>Blue</Color>
<Color>Green</Color>
<Color>Indigo</Color>
<Color>Violet</Color>';

SELECT @MyXml.query('<Colors>{.}</Colors>');
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server has a good build-in support for work with XML. There is no need to store a `XML tag` in your column.

You should remove the unnecessary `<Color>` tag in order to optimize the work with XML and reduce the column storage - it is easy to generate it when it is needed like this:

```
SELECT [color]
FROM DataSource FOR XML PATH('Color'), ROOT('Colors')
```

In you are not allowed to do this, you can remove the tags with SQL like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DataSource
(
  [color] VARCHAR(32) 
)

INSERT INTO DataSource ([color])
VALUES ('<Color>Red</Color>')
      ,('<Color>Orange</Color>')
      ,('<Color>Yellow</Color>')
      ,('<Color>Blue</Color>')
      ,('<Color>Green</Color>')
      ,('<Color>Indigo</Color>')
      ,('<Color>Violet</Color>')

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE([color],'<Color>',''),'</Color>','')
FROM DataSource FOR XML PATH('Color'), ROOT('Colors')
```

But the above seems very wrong for me and I will advise you to change the way you are storing the values in the table.

Comment: Column's data type is XML. OP has updated the question.

Comment: This is good advice. As it applies I'll remember it. In the actual application I'm reusing a procedure that already returns the data in XML. I put the results in a temp table and use the query to prepare a Service Broker message.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it, I hope it will work

```
select color from MyColorTable for xml path('Colors')
```

or

```
select columnname as 'color' from MyColorTable for xml path('Colors')
```

Comment: Nope, the `FOR XML PATH('Colors')` will put a `<Colors>...</Colors>` around **each and every single entry** in the table ..... not what the OP is looking for